# Self hosted google font not smooth in any browser

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I got the "Lato" google font and want to self-host it (because of performance). I got it implemented and it looks shitty and not smooth in any browser, it looks really pixelated!

[image]

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: 'lato';
    src: url('font/latoFont.eot');
    src: url('font/latoFont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('font/latoFont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('font/latoFont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('font/latoFont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
}

html {
    font-family: 'lato', sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1.4rem;
    color: #212121;
}
```

What can i do to get more satisfying and smooth results?

Comment: Does it only look that way when you self-host?

Comment: Give me a second, i will try to implement the remote one.

Comment: it seems that with the remote one i've got the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this hotfix

```
/*FIX FONT FOR GOOGLE CHROME ON WINDOWS*/
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'MyFont';
        src: url('fonts/myfont.svg#myfont') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;}
}
```

You can read more [here](https://www.domsammut.com/code/some-solutions-to-font-face-rendering-poorly-in-windows-google-chrome)

Comment: it seems to has no impact on that problem.

Comment: Which more lines do you need for a look? On my post i got the relevant lines i think?